# ReactJS: useNavigate hook route change doubles all renders

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react 18.2` and `react-router-dom 6.3` and use functional components. For navigating between my routes, I use the useNavigate hook.

I had a performance problem and started to log everything and noticed that I have double the amount of logs when I use useNavigate instead of just typing the url in my browser and just load the page this way.

Example code below for this scenario:

I have the **Main** component on "/" and the **Start** component on "/start".

The **Main** component contains a link (with useNavigate) to "/start". The **Start** component logs "test" on the initial render (in the useEffect).

If I use the useNavigate link in the **Main** component, "test" is logged two times and if I just type in "URL/start" in the browser, "test" is logged only one time. On my production environment this translates to the doubling of all api calls I do in the component with which I get into limit errors.

**App.js**

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.scss";
import LoadingSpinner from "./components/structure/LoadingSpinner.js";

const Main = lazy(() => import("./components/content/Main.js"));
const Start = lazy(() => import("./components/content/Start.js"));

export default function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner/>}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<Main/>}/>
                    <Route exact path="/start" element={<Start/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

**Main.js:**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function NotFound() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    function handleRouteChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        navigate(path);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <a href="/start" onClick={(event) => handleRouteChange(event)}></a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Start.js:**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Start() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("test");
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            hello
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you validating/verifying component renders? Please [edit] to provide an accurate [mcve] for what you are doing in your code.

Comment: @DrewReese I edited it and hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Are you rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component? React 18 `StrictMode` mounts components twice as part of [ensuring reusable state](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state). This is expected behavior in non-production builds. You are also issuing ***two*** navigation actions per click of a link, one by the link itself and the other by an attached `onClick` handler that calls the `navigate` function. You only need one of these methods.

Comment: Yes, I use ```React.StrictMode``` and was not aware of the doubled mounting. But to be clear, the issue also happens in my production build.  
As for the **two** navigation actions: I thought that the ```event.preventDefault();``` prevented the action by the link itself and it would be fine, but apparently it does not prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two event triggers:

1. `href` attribute is a trigger for the browser to navigate to `/start` and the `handleRouteChange(event)` does not explicitly return `false` returning [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), which is falsy but not `false`.
2. `navigate(path)` in the `handleRouteChange()` function.

```html
<div>
    <a href="/start" onClick={(event) => handleRouteChange(event)}></a>
</div>
```

Ideally, [you should not use `onClick` with anchors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#onclick_events).

Suggested fix: change the anchor tag `<a></a>` to `<button></button>`

Minimal fix (not recommended): add `return false` to the `handleRouteChange()` function.

```
    function handleRouteChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        navigate(path);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The problem by using a <button> is that I cannot use it as a typical link anymore. For example, it is not possible to open a new tab by using the middle mouse button. Unfortunately, adding the ```return false``` did not change anything.

Comment: In that case you do not need the `onClick`, simply use `<Link to="/start">...</Link>`

Comment: Using Link and ignoring my ```<a/>``` setup works, but the problem stays. ```"test"``` is still printed two times or in my environment: all api calls are are calculated two times.

Comment: Also, just for the sake of completeness, ` <React.StrictMode> ...</React.StrictMode>` would render twice (https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode). Did you try without it or observe the same issue in a deploy build of your application? From what I understood, your question mentioned that you were observing the double call in a deploy build as well.

Comment: Yes, I can also observe the double call in the deploy build. There I still think that it does not have to do with the StrictMode. The problem still persists with all suggested changes.